# XAML: Is there a way to simulate IsPressed with a ComboBoxItem?

Tags: xaml, combobox

I want to simulate a Button `IsPressed` event for a `ComboBoxItem`.

Is this possible strictly in XAML?

I know how to in code-behind as well as changing the Style or Template but I was hoping to accomplish this in XAML with a Standard `ComboBoxItem`.

TIA